# How do you use jQuery filter() on an attribute that is not a class or id

Tags: jquery, filter, attributes

I want to filter based on an attribute called "level".

Where I have written -- something here -- I don't know what to do to reference the level attribute. If it was an id attribute I would do #idName if it was a class I would do .className.

I am not sure what to do to select the level attribute.

> $(".myClass").filter(--something here to reference the level attribute --).remove();

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`filter("[level='2']")`

Answer (score 11):

No need for `filter`, just use the [attribute filter](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) syntax, in this case, the [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$(".myClass[level]").remove();
```

That should remove all `.myClass` elements that have a non-empty `level`, of course, you could  for instance match `level`'s based on one of the several available operators (see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)), such as [startsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$(".myClass[level^=foo]").remove(); // remove the ones that start with 'foo'
```

[contains:](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$(".myClass[level*=haa]").remove(); // remove the ones that contain 'haa'
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do something complicated, you can write a [filter function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) that returns true for the elements that should be in the filtered set.

Comment: Whilst this is not the best approach in this case, for completeness sake, this could be done as follows:  `.filter(function () { return this.level == 'something'; });` (where `this` is the current DOM element)

Comment: Agreed - I gave +1's to the nice solutions below. Thanks for the comment.